# Golang Unmarshal slice of type interface

Tags: json, go, struct, interface, unmarshalling

In this example, I would be trying to load 2D scenes that contain polygons. In the code, I would have many different structs such as Circle, Square, Rectangle, Pentagon, etc.. 
All would share common *funcs*, such as Area and Perimeter. 
The scene itself would be stored as a slice of the interface Polygon.

Here is the code I'm using to test this:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Polygon interface {
    Area() float32
}

type Rectangle struct {
    Base   float32 `json:"base"`
    Height float32 `json:"height"`
    X      float32 `json:"x"`
    Y      float32 `json:"y"`
}

func (r *Rectangle) Area() float32 {
    return r.Base * r.Height
}

type Circle struct {
    Radius float32 `json:"radius"`
    X      float32 `json:"x"`
    Y      float32 `json:"y"`
}

func (c *Circle) Area() float32 {
    return c.Radius * c.Radius * math.Pi
}

func main() {
    rect := Rectangle{Base: 10, Height: 10, X: 10, Y: 10}
    circ := Circle{Radius: 10, X: 0, Y: 0}

    sliceOfPolygons := make([]Polygon, 0, 2)

    sliceOfPolygons = append(sliceOfPolygons, &rect, &circ)

    jsonData, err := json.Marshal(sliceOfPolygons)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(jsonData))

    newSlice := make([]Polygon, 0)

    err = json.Unmarshal(jsonData, &newSlice)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

In this example, I setup a slice of 2 polygons, marshal it and then try to unmarshal it again. 
The marshal-ed string is:

```
[{"base":10,"height":10,"x":10,"y":10},{"radius":10,"x":0,"y":0}]
```

But when I try to `Unmarshal` it panics:

```
panic: json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type main.Polygon
```

If this worked it would be really useful and simple to use. I'd say that `Unmarshall` can't distinguish between a `Rectangle` and a `Circle` from the json string so it can't possibly know what struct to build.

Is there any way to tag the struct or tell `Unmarshal` how to distinguish this structs?

Comment: `Polygon` is an interface, you can't pass `interface` to unmarshaler. You must pass *a concrete* type. *Quick* solution is unmarshal it to `[]map[string]interface{}`,  but then you need to *convert* it to struct manually. If you're allowed to change the data structure, use [`json.RawMessage` to delay parsing part of your JSON](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought that way to distinguish whether the json is Circle or Rectangle. In your JSON, there is no identify for the struct which can detect kind of objects. So let's make rules.

- Rectangle have base and height both greater than 0
- Circle have radius greater than 0

To unmarshal JSON, it should have commonly fields like below.

```
type Object struct {
    Base   float32 `json:"base,omitempty"`
    Radius float32 `json:"radius,omitempty"`
    Height float32 `json:"height,omitempty"`
    X      float32 `json:"x"`
    Y      float32 `json:"y"`
}
```

This struct can be stored Rectangle or Circle both. Then, add method IsCircle and IsRectangle.

```
func (obj *Object) IsCircle() bool {
    return obj.Radius > 0
}

func (obj *Object) IsRectangle() bool {
    return obj.Base > 0 && obj.Height > 0
}
```

You can make method like Kind() to return identity of struct instead. As you think best. Finally, you should add ToCircle/ToRectangle methods.

```
func (obj *Object) ToCircle() *Circle {
    return &Circle{
        Radius: obj.Radius,
        X:      obj.X,
        Y:      obj.Y,
    }
}

func (obj *Object) ToRectangle() *Rectangle {
    return &Rectangle{
        Base:   obj.Base,
        Height: obj.Height,
        X:      obj.X,
        Y:      obj.Y,
    }
}
```

If you want slice of Polygon interface, you should convert this slice of Object to the slice of Polygon like below.

```
var polygons []Polygon
for _, obj := range newSlice {
    if obj.IsCircle() {
        polygons = append(polygons, obj.ToCircle())
    } else if obj.IsRectangle() {
        polygons = append(polygons, obj.ToRectangle())
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/kO_F4GTYdA

### UPDATE

One another approach. Make converters which convert from map[string]interface{}. The converter can detect the struct with looking fields exists.

```
var converters = []func(map[string]interface{}) Polygon{
    func(m map[string]interface{}) Polygon {
        rectangle := new(Rectangle)
        if base, ok := m["base"]; ok {
            rectangle.Base = toFloat32(base)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        if height, ok := m["height"]; ok {
            rectangle.Height = toFloat32(height)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        if x, ok := m["x"]; ok {
            rectangle.X = toFloat32(x)
        }
        if y, ok := m["y"]; ok {
            rectangle.Y = toFloat32(y)
        }
        return rectangle
    },
    func(m map[string]interface{}) Polygon {
        circle := new(Circle)
        if radius, ok := m["radius"]; ok {
            circle.Radius = toFloat32(radius)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        if x, ok := m["x"]; ok {
            circle.X = toFloat32(x)
        }
        if y, ok := m["y"]; ok {
            circle.Y = toFloat32(y)
        }
        return circle
    },
}
```

And do convert

```
var polygons []Polygon
for _, obj := range newSlice {
    m, ok := obj.(map[string]interface{})
    if !ok {
        panic("invalid struct")
    }
    var p Polygon
    for _, converter := range converters {
        p = converter(m)
        if p != nil {
            break
        }
    }
    if p == nil {
        panic("unknown polygon")
    }
    polygons = append(polygons, p)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/PrxiMOa_1F

Comment: I wanted to avoid a solution in this form since it could be less efficient to have a struct that can hold all possible values. Also, it just doesn't look as pretty (in my opinion). It should work though, since polygons don't have so many different kinds of values it's not so bad.

Comment: added another approach.

Comment: Depending on rectangles having radius = 0 and such conditions still doesn't sound very appealing to me. At that point, I'd find it easier to specify the type of the struct that is being defined and parse the map manually.

Comment: second approach doesn't look `radius = 0`. so I guess you want the second.

Comment: Checking whether the value is there at all is pretty much the same. In this example it could be fine, but in general some "polygons" (as in, the general type) could share elements from others. Adding new ones would change the whole convert functions, making them harder to maintain.

Comment: That is unreasonable thing. Because your JSON does not have type information or kind of struct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148177/discussion-between-mjgalindo-and-mattn).